# Grab File Path in C + WebkitGTK

Tags: c, gtk

I'm trying to compile my web app as a native desktop application in C. However I'm having a bit of trouble grabbing the file path in C.

In PyGTK I would use...

```
import webkit, pygtk, gtk, os

path=os.getcwd()
print path
web_view.open("file://" + path + "/index.html")
```

However I'm not sure if I'm just looking in the wrong places or what, but when I search Google I haven't been able to find out how to grab the file path in C which I want to use like this.

```
gchar* uri = (gchar*) (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "file://" + path + "app/index.html");
```

Instead of linking to it in a grotesque manner like so...

```
gchar* uri = (gchar*) (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "file://" + /home/michael/Desktop/kodeWeave/linux/app/index.html");
webkit_web_view_open (web_view, uri);
```

Here's my full project (if helpful).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <webkit/webkit.h>

static WebKitWebView* web_view;

void on_window_destroy (GtkObject *object, gpointer user_data) {
  gtk_main_quit();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  GtkBuilder *builder;
  GtkWidget  *window;
  GtkWidget  *scrolled_window;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  builder = gtk_builder_new();
  gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "browser.xml", NULL);
  window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "window1"));
  scrolled_window = GTK_WIDGET (gtk_builder_get_object (builder, "scrolledwindow1"));
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "delete-event", gtk_main_quit, NULL);

  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "kodeWeave");

  web_view = WEBKIT_WEB_VIEW (webkit_web_view_new());
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (scrolled_window), GTK_WIDGET (web_view));

  gtk_builder_connect_signals (builder, NULL);

  g_object_unref (G_OBJECT (builder));

  gchar* uri = (gchar*) (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "file:///home/michael/Desktop/kodeWeave/linux/app/index.html");
  webkit_web_view_open (web_view, uri);

  gtk_widget_grab_focus (GTK_WIDGET (web_view));
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `+` operator to concatenate strings in c, you may need `snprintf` instead, first you need a large enough buffer, may be the constant `PATH_MAX` will work, it's defined in `limits.h`, so for example

```
char uri[PATH_MAX];
char cwd[PATH_MAX];

getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));

if (argc > 1)
    snprintf(uri, sizeof(uri), "%s", argv[1]);
else
    snprintf(uri, sizeof(uri), "file://%s/index.html", cwd);
    /*                                  ^ %s specifier for ^ this char pointer */
```

the `+` operator works with your operands, but in a different way, it just performs pointer arithmetic, because the operands are pointers.

Comment: Is there a way around the main path? What if I move the folder, rename the directory, or use on another computer with a different username? I don't want it to be reliant on that specific location.

Comment: Since this is a GTK+ program and GTK+ uses GLib, [GLib has a bunch of string helpers](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html) that will avoid needing a static, fixed-size buffer (be aware that you have to free the memory at runtime when finished) [as well as functions that are better suited for building URLs than simple string concatenation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-URI-Functions.html).

Comment: @andlabs nice link, that's very interesting. But I believe the OP would be confused with those functions, since clearly the OP does not understand how strings are possible in c and how to handle them.

Comment: Yes. (My point was more "no need for `PATH_MAX` in your answer.) Unfortunately traditional C strings are fixed-size buffers... and since I'm not a Python programmer (I only know a bit of it), I'm not sure what teaching material to provide that would be best.

Comment: @mikethedj4 the constant `path` string in the answer is an example. In the `snprintf()` line you can substitute `argv[1]` for `path` and it would work. Think about how formatted strings work in Python (`%` operator and all that); in C they work the same way.

Comment: @andlabs you made me realize that he wants the current working directory where `path` is, see the first chunk of code, the python code.